# Get records count from multi tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables Box, Documemts, Batches.
each box contain more than 1 document and each document has multi batches.
i want to Select count of documents in Boxs where at least 1 batch in the document has the value IsDeleted = 0.

let us assume that document has 10 batches, if at least one batch has the value isdeleted = 0
we will count it, else if all batches have the isdeleted = 1 we will not count it.

How can I select the number od document based on the above?

i tried this but it is not work

```
SELECT b.ID as BOXID,d.ID as DocID, count(1) as CountDoc 
  FROM Documents as d 
 INNER JOIN dbo.Boxes as b on d.boxid = b.id 
 INNER JOIN dbo.Batches as t on d.ID = t.DocumentID 
 WHERE d.ID = t.DocumentID 
   AND d.boxid= b.id 
   AND t.isDeleted = 0 
 GROUP BY d.ID , t.DocumentID ,b.ID --HAVING t.isDeleted = 0
```

Comment: i tried this but it is not work                                     select b.ID as BOXID,d.ID as DocID, count(1) as CountDoc 
from Documents as d inner join dbo.Boxes as b on d.boxid = b.id 
                    INNER JOIN dbo.Batches as t on d.ID = t.DocumentID 
                    
 where d.ID = t.DocumentID AND d.boxid= b.id AND t.isDeleted = 0 
 GROUP BY d.ID , t.DocumentID ,b.ID
 --HAVING t.isDeleted = 0

Comment: You can edit your question anytime. So add your code/schema in your question instead of comment.

Comment: Can you give us the table structure?

Comment: Side note: don't repeat join conditions in where, it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select boxid, count(distinct documentid)
from 
    documents
         inner join batches
    on documents.id = batches.documentid
where
    isdeleted = 0
group by boxid
```